# Android Studio drawBitmap on a Canvas not working

Tags: java, android, mobile, canvas, android-studio

I want to draw an image onto my canvas of my Android Application in Android Studio. The c.drawBitmap() function has an error.
It says: 'Cannot resolve method 'drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, int, int, int, int)'

```
Bitmap bg;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  bg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg);
  ...
}
public void run() {
  ...
  Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
  c.drawBitmap(bg, 100, 100, 400, 200); // error occurs here
  ...
}
```

I am completely new to Android development and I could not find a solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have the wrong parameters.  You want either [drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, Paint paint)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) or       [drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint))